# Finding the quotient and remainder when dividing $f = 2018X^{2019} - 2019X^{2018} + 1$ to $(X-1)^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

> Let $f = 2018X^{2019} - 2019X^{2018} + 1, f \in \mathbb{R}[X]$. Find the quotient and the remainder when dividing $f$ to $(X-1)^2$.

The answer to this problem is that $f = (X-1)^2(2018X^{2017} + 2017X^{2016} + \cdots + 2X + 1)$. My question is: is there any way of obtaining this result in an elegant way, rather than by simply brute-forcing the long division and spotting the solution?

Comment: Is X a real number? or a matrix?

Comment: It's the indeterminate from the ring $\mathbb{R}[X]$, so a real number.

Comment: __Hint:__ Let $f(X) = q(X)(X-1)^2 + aX+b$. Evaluate $f(1)$ and $f'(1)$ to find $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Related: [Prove that the polynomial $f_n(x)=nx^{n+1}-(n+1)x^n+1$ is divisible by $(x-1)^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2079719/prove-that-the-polynomial-f-nx-nxn1-n1xn1-is-divisible-by-x-12/) (not a duplicate since it's not asking for the quotient).

Comment: @Morărescu  The divisibility is clear from the [double root test](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/127794/242), and the simple recurive formula for the quotient is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2079744/242) in the dupe.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly brute force, but the neat answer allows us to use the [synthetic division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_division) to find the answer.

*Sorry for the picture, I'll try to format them with MathJax, but it might take a while.*

First, by evaluating $f(1)$, we can find the remainder of the division by $(X-1)$
$$f(1) = 2018\cdot 1^{2019} - 2019 \cdot 1^{2018} + 1 = 0$$
Now dividing $f(X)$ by $(X-1)$
$$
\begin{array}{r|rrrrrrrr}
1&2018&-2019&0&0&0&\dots&0&1\\
&&2018&-1&-1&-1&\dots&-1&-1\\\hline
&2018&-1&-1&-1&-1&\dots&-1&0
\end{array}$$
[image]
$$f(X) = (X-1) (2018X^{2018} - X^{2017} - X^{2016} - X^{2015} - \dots - X^1 - 1)$$

This new polynomial is also divisible by $(X-1)$. Let's do the synthetic division again.
$$
\begin{array}{r|rrrrrrrr}
1&2018&-1&-1&-1&-1&\dots&-1&-1\\
&&2018&2017&2016&2015&\dots&2&1\\\hline
&2018&2017&2016&2015&2014&\dots&1&0
\end{array}$$
[image]
Giving us the desired answer
$$f(X) = (X-1)^2(2018X^{2017} + 2017X^{2016} + 2016X^{2015} + \dots + 2X^1 + 1)$$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{align}
f(X) &= 2018X^{2019} - 2019X^{2018} + 1
\\ &= 2018 X^{2018}\left(X - 1\right) - \left(X^{2018} - 1\right)
\\ &= \left(X - 1\right)2018 X^{2018} - \left(X - 1\right)\left(X^{2017}+ X^{2016} + \dots + 1\right)
\\ &= (X-1)\left(\left(X^{2018} - X^{2017}\right) + \left(X^{2018} - X^{2016}\right)+\dots+\left(X^{2018} - 1\right)\right)
\\ &= (X-1)^2\left(X^{2017} + X^{2016}(X+1) + X^{2015}\left(X^2+X+1\right)+\dots
\\ +X^0\cdot\left(X^{2017}+X^{2016}+\dots+1\right)\right)
\\ &= \dots
\end{align}
$$